# Dask worker failing to deserialize task

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, fastparquet

I added new node to the dask cluster and installed all dependencies using conda. The installation is similar in terms of package and version on all dask nodes.

However task on the new node failing with below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parquet_thrift'
```

[ worker .... ] : distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not deserialize task

All other nodes work fine. 
FYI:
All nodes have fast parquet installed.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Does `client.get_versions(check=True)` pass?

Comment: Yes MR, client.get_versions(check=True) passes successfully.

Comment: Please make sure you have fastparquet 0.1.2